# How to add grouping to a complex linq query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, grouping

I currently have a working query that pulls data from several SQL tables for display in a kendo ui grid. I've now been tasked with adding grouping to the query but I haven't been able to successfully add grouping that will return data. All my attempts so far result in empty data-sets.

I have tried adding a group by clause, "group new {quotes, t, s, rfqStarred, ch} by new {quotes.QuoteExpirationTerm} into qgroup" which results in an empty data-set. I am also unable to use any date fields in the query once I've added the grouping.

There are over 100 fields returned by the query so I've removed most to try to minimalize my example.

The following is a snippet from the working query with no grouping:

```
var query = from m in db.RfqQuoteIntermediates
            from quotes in db.Quotes.Where(q => q.Id == m.QuoteId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from t in db.SEWPRfqs.Where(r => r.RfqId == m.RfqId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from s in db.RfqSupplementals.Where(x => x.RfqSeqNumber == t.RfqSeqNumber).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from rfqStarred in db.RfqUserStarreds.Where(rs => rs.RfqSeqNumber == t.RfqSeqNumber && rs.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
            let ch = db.RfqsChangeHistories.Where(r => r.RfqRfiSeqNum == t.RfqSeqNumber && (r.Action == "RFQ marked 'Hot'" || r.Action == "RFQ unmarked 'Hot'" || r.Action == "Quote Close Date Change" || r.Action == "Hot Change Comment" 
            || r.Action == "New Comment" || r.Action == "New RFQ Comment" || r.Action == "New Quote Comment" || r.Action == "Close Date Change Comment" || r.Action == "Stage Change Comment")).OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
            where (whereSelector == "allPipelineRfqs"
            || (whereSelector == "pipelineRfqs" && (quotes.QuoteStage == "Pipeline" || quotes.QuoteStage == "Swing" || quotes.QuoteStage == "Forecast"))
            || (whereSelector == "closedWon" && quotes.QuoteStage == "Closed-Won")
            || (whereSelector == "closedLost" && quotes.QuoteStage == "Closed-Lost")
            || (whereSelector == "today" && quotes.QuoteDate.Date >= today)
            || (whereSelector == "thisWeek" && startOfWeek <= quotes.QuoteDate && quotes.QuoteDate < endOfWeek)
            || (whereSelector == "lastWeek" && startOfWeek <= quotes.QuoteDate && quotes.QuoteDate < endOfWeek))
            && (isAdmin || t.assignedTo == salesrep || t.secndAssignedTo == salesrep || t.addlAssignedTo == salesrep || agencies.Contains(t.Agency))
            && t.IsDeleted == false && t.IsInPipeline
            select new PipelineDto()
            {
                RfqId = t.RfqId,
                Contract = t.Contract,
                RfqSeqNumber = t.RfqSeqNumber,

        .... fields removed for example

                IsInPipeline = t.IsInPipeline,
                VendorRationale = t.VendorRationale,
                LastUpdated = t.LastUpdated,
                Acronym = s.AgencyAcronym,
                SubAcronym = s.SubAgencyAcronym,
                userstarred = rfqStarred != null,
                QuoteId = quotes.Id,
                QuoteNumber = quotes.QuoteNumber,
                QuoteDate = quotes.QuoteDate.ToShortDateString(),
                QuoteSalesContact = quotes.QuoteSalesContact,
                QuotedBy = quotes.QuotedBy,
                QuoteTotal = quotes.QuoteTotal,
                QuoteExpirationTerm = quotes.QuoteExpirationTerm,
                ActionInfo = s.ActionInfo,
                AssignedDate = s.ActionInfoDate,
                CommentNotificationLastViewed = db.RfqCommentNotifications.Where(r => r.RfqSequenceNum == t.RfqSeqNumber && r.SalesRep == salesrep).Select(d=>d.LastViewed).SingleOrDefault(),
                CommentActionDate = ch.ActionDate,
                CommentAction = ch.Action,
                CommentActionBy = ch.ActionBy
            };
```

Here is what I have so far in my non-working group by query:

```
var query = from m in db.RfqQuoteIntermediates
            from quotes in db.Quotes.Where(q => q.Id == m.QuoteId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from t in db.SEWPRfqs.Where(r => r.RfqId == m.RfqId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from s in db.RfqSupplementals.Where(x => x.RfqSeqNumber == t.RfqSeqNumber).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from rfqStarred in db.RfqUserStarreds.Where(rs => rs.RfqSeqNumber == t.RfqSeqNumber && rs.SalesRep == salesrep).DefaultIfEmpty()
            let ch = db.RfqsChangeHistories.Where(r => r.RfqRfiSeqNum == t.RfqSeqNumber && (r.Action == "RFQ marked 'Hot'" || r.Action == "RFQ unmarked 'Hot'" || r.Action == "Quote Close Date Change" || r.Action == "Hot Change Comment" 
            || r.Action == "New Comment" || r.Action == "New RFQ Comment" || r.Action == "New Quote Comment" || r.Action == "Close Date Change Comment" || r.Action == "Stage Change Comment")).OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
            where (whereSelector == "allPipelineRfqs"
            || (whereSelector == "pipelineRfqs" && (quotes.QuoteStage == "Pipeline" || quotes.QuoteStage == "Swing" || quotes.QuoteStage == "Forecast"))
            || (whereSelector == "closedWon" && quotes.QuoteStage == "Closed-Won")
            || (whereSelector == "closedLost" && quotes.QuoteStage == "Closed-Lost")
            || (whereSelector == "today" && quotes.QuoteDate.Date >= today)
            || (whereSelector == "thisWeek" && startOfWeek <= quotes.QuoteDate && quotes.QuoteDate < endOfWeek)
            || (whereSelector == "lastWeek" && startOfWeek <= quotes.QuoteDate && quotes.QuoteDate < endOfWeek))
            && (isAdmin || t.assignedTo == salesrep || t.secndAssignedTo == salesrep || t.addlAssignedTo == salesrep || agencies.Contains(t.Agency))
            && t.IsDeleted == false && t.IsInPipeline

            group new {quotes, t, s, rfqStarred, ch} by new {quotes.QuoteExpirationTerm} into qgroup

            select new PipelineDto()
            {
                RfqId = Convert.ToInt32(qgroup.Select(g => g.t.RfqId)),
                Contract = qgroup.Select(g => g.t.Contract).ToString(),
                RfqSeqNumber = qgroup.Select(g => g.t.RfqSeqNumber).ToString(),
                //RFQ_RFIDate = Convert.ToDateTime(qgroup.Select(g=>g.t.RFQ_RFIDate),   * everything below this wile not compile it I uncomment any of the dates. 
                BidStatus = qgroup.Select(g => g.t.BidStatus).ToString(),
                ModLevel = qgroup.Select(g => g.t.ModLevel).ToString(),
                //ModDate = Convert.ToDateTime(qgroup.Select(g=>g.t.ModDate)),      * same here and next field.
                //ReplyByDate = Convert.ToDateTime(qgroup.Select(g=>g.t.ReplyByDate),

        .... the rest of the fields

            };
```

How do I do the grouping on the quotes.QuoteExpirationTerm (an int with a value of 30, 60 or 90 days) that will return data and what do I need to change on date fields to be able to include the dates in the query.

Expected results are groupings by 30, 60 and 90 days but so far I can only get empty data-sets.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @stuartd Thank you for fixing the formatting.

Comment: No problem. Single backtick for inline code, triple backticks (and newlines) for blocks.

Comment: When you say _"everything below this will not compile it I uncomment any of the dates"_ - what compiler error do you get?

Comment: Actually a bad description on my part there Stuart. When I uncomment a date field any field below that in my PipelineDto class does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Types are your friend. What is the type of `qgroup`? What is the type of `qgroup.Select(`...`)`? What type does `Convert.ToDateTime()` expect? What type is `qgroup.Select(g=>g.t.RFQ_RFIDate)`? IOTW, what does `group`...`by` do?